# Can I let my android get to 50% before it starts charging? Or is this not supported

Tags: android

Seems a little odd at first but yes I want to be able to stop the nexus 7 from charging until it hits some amount (30-50 percent).

The reason is I will be using the nexus in a industrial situation where you will need to get say 10-15 hours out of it, and there is a 12v battery powering the other devices being used. So, if needed, we can use the battery to charge the tablet but then it will run out quickly.

My original idea is to have the android tell the other control device I am using that it is low on battery and then a physical switch will be triggered which will let the power line in the usb cable have 5v and begin charging. Obviously, if it could all be handled in software that would be better.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a low amperage charger? Then it will constantly charge but at a slower rate. A 500mA charger will charge at a very slow rate and only put half the drain on your 12V battery as compared to a 1A charger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main reason is that the total current cons of the circuit is around 100-200 mA. Adding 500mA onto that will make the 12v battery drain quite quickly. Ideally, the 12v battery will be as small as possible to ensure 10+ hours of continuous use.